# Debian/kfreebsd VirtualBox guest additions

Tags: debian, freebsd, virtualbox

I'm trying and failing to install the virtualbox guest additions for a unstable Debian/kfreebsd virtual machine running in VirtualBox.  Without the guest additions, the idle process pegs one of my CPU cores.

I've tried to install the `virtualbox-guest-additions-dkms` package, but that depends on `virtualbox-guest-utils` which apparently isn't packaged for Debian/kfreebsd.

I've grabbed the `virtualbox-guest-additions-iso` package and tried to compile that but no luck there either, even with the kernel-headers installed.

I've also tried install `kfreebsd-9.2-source` and compile the iso package and the source package that way but I only get "no targets found".

VirtualBox does not come with FreeBSD guest additions, but there are [guest additions for FreeBSD](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/virtualization-guest.html) in the `emulators/virtualbox-ose-additions` port on FreeBSD. I'm looking for the equivalent of this port on Debian.

Anyone have any thoughts?

Comment: I thought VirtualBox didn't provide guest additions for FreeBSD. Where did you find guest additions for FreeBSD?

Comment: It's in apt.  It might just be the Linux version, but regardless it's there.  Whether or not it works, that's what I was hoping someone here could tell me and if it's possible explain how to make it work.

Comment: @Gilles - on a plain FreeBSD system, the guest additions are available in the emulators/virtualbox-ose-additions port.

Answer (score 1):

You need to file a bug with the Debian/kFreeBSD developers, as with the current version of the Virtualbox package in Debian, they do not have the appropriate code in place to allow compiling of the guest additions modules within the hybrid environment that is kFreeBSD.

You can build the guest additions on native FreeBSD, but likely due to the fact that Debian used gcc-4.8.x and FreeBSD is sticking with gcc-4.2.1, the module will be incompatible with kFreeBSD's running kernel.

Gcc-4.8.x is in FreeBSD's Ports, though, so you could try installing that and then seeing if a native FreeBSD install can build working modules for you.